# Why is -48V used?

Tags: voltage, ground, electric-machine, telecommunications

Why does telecommunications equipment in the field (e.g. a BTS site) run on -48V? What is the advantage of running it at a voltage lower than ground rather than using a positive voltage?

Comment: I was about to post about the corrosive aspect but you found a dup

Answer (score 0):

To reduce electrochemical reaction on grounded metal poles or parts which form a part of the circuit.  Ionic reaction tend to move particles from negative (cathode) to positive ( anode).

Thus, by having the negative part of the circuit grounded, the metals associated with that grounding points will stay more healthy.

Comment: If it's a -48V supply, then isn't the *positive* side of the circuit grounded?

Comment: Simon B, you are right... I miss spoke here. Wrong fact...!! I'm sorry